# Longest common suffix of two strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I am looking for the easiest way to find the longest common suffix of two strings in JavaScript.

I found [a question about longest common prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702774/longest-common-prefix-in-javascript) but

- (a) it's general question for an array of strings instead of just two strings which adds unnecessary complexity to the code for my need
- (b) it's prefix, not suffix. I could reverse the input strings before and after running the prefix algorithm to get the same result but that didn't felt easier to read in the future so I'm rather looking for the shortest, most self-explanatory code snippet.

Comment: So reverse it?? :)

Comment: Even though this is a "documentary" Q & A, the question should still be written as normal. What you've tried, etc. Why reversing the longest common suffix wasn't good enough (e.g., you can reverse the input strings, but would prefer a modified algorithm). And same goes for the answer; it's still a normal answer, and should be written as such.

Comment: Sure!.. my original intention was to make it as short as possible but I don't mind adding context. Check it out then, I've attempted to improve both Q&A based on your input.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783217/find-longest-common-suffix-without-recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterates over the characters of the two strings in reverse order until it finds a difference.

```
const commonSuffix = (str1: string, str2: string) => {
    for (let i1 = str1.length - 1, i2 = str2.length - 1; i1 >= 0 && i2 >= 0; i1--, i2--) {
        if (str1[i1] !== str2[i2]) {
            return str1.substr(i1 + 1);
        }
    }
    return str1.length < str2.length ? str1 : str2;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
function longestCommonSuffix(str1, str2) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < str1.length && i < str2.length && str1[str1.length - 1 - i] === str2[str2.length - 1 - i]) {
        i++;
    }
    return str1.slice(str1.length - i);
}

// Example usage:
console.log(longestCommonSuffix("programming", "coding")); // Outputs: "ing"
console.log(longestCommonSuffix("hello", "world"));       // Outputs: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I am providing an alternate solution which first transforms the strings into arrays then finds the common suffix.

```js
let a = '123567';
let b = '124567';

function commonSuffix(a, b) {
  let arrayA = [...a].reverse(), arrayB = [...b].reverse();
                
  let match = [];
  arrayA.every((item, i) => arrayB[i] === item && match.unshift(item));
  return match.join('');
}

console.log(commonSuffix(a, b));
```